# How to setup Xampp server for android Chatting App?

Tags: xampp, ejabberd, smack

The best way would be to use XMPP libraries such as aSmack or the newer Smack. i will need an XMPP server such as OpenFire or eJabberd running on some Hosting before you can build a mobile app.But how it work and implement?.because i have android knowledge.but no any idea of server.

Comment: That is not really a question that can be answered. "I have no idea of servers": Well, then read up. We can't explain what servers do, how to chose one and what you need in a short answer.

Comment: That's the beauty of a server.  It doesn't have to know who is talking to it.  Set up the server like you would if it were responding to a normal web application (ideally using RESTful json).  If you don't know what I mean by that, then study up on backend before continuing.

Comment: i have all setup. android side this link https://github.com/viniciusthiengo/push-message-serie and server side https://github.com/viniciusthiengo/push-message-serie-web

Answer (score 1):

you should use ejabberd in my opinion.Download ejabberd and install it for configuration check this link http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/
ejabberd is an open source Jabber/XMPP server.
Ejabberd is a Rock Solid, Massively Scalable, Infinitely Extensible XMPP Server. 
for more details check these links-

```
 https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/
 https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-massive-scalability-1node-2-million-concurrent-users/
```